# How to debug phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, webview, phonegap-plugins

I am using [phonegap desktop](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/03/02/phonegap-app-desktop-0-1-2/) (on Windows 7 64) and the [phonegap android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app) to test my code in real time, without having to make a new build each time I want to check how it is looking.

The problem is I have no idea how to debug using this method.

In my opinion the best option would be using google chrome "USB Device" WebView debuging feature, but it looks like the phonegap app used to try the app doesn't allow chrome to debug the WebView, because I can see my device listed in "chrome://inspect", I can see any chrome tab if there is any opened, but I can't see the WebView used by the phonegap android app.

If you have any idea, thank you.

Comment: I just use `chrome://inspect#devices` to debug my cordova app. It is no issue here.

Comment: @MarkVeenstra Ok but are you using phonegap desktop app with phonegap android app? Because I do not see anything exept the device connected, but I can't find the WebView to inspect...

Comment: No cordova from the cli

Comment: @MarkVeenstra ok and do you use the android phonegap app?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way how you can get close to "Debug" is using console.log() while running your app in a web-server and connect with phonegap-app on your device.
I know two ways to do this:

- [Use the desktop app](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/11/phonegap-desktop-app-beta/)
- [With command `phonegap serve`](http://app.phonegap.com/)

But recently I found [Telerik AppBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder). There is a possibility to debug like I have not better found it. It's just not free, but you can try the trial period.

Unless just try to work/debug long as possible in Firefox/Chrome...etc

Comment: First thank you. I will give a look at the Telerik AppBuilder, even if I would prefer a free solution. As for the console.log() advice, I don't understand where you find the console log using the phonegap app on my device, where can you see what is looged?

Comment: There is a button to open the Server log console. Between the phonegap app logs should be your console.log's listed as well.

Comment: But i suggest to use your own console and "phonegap serve" with maybe an altenative console-program like I do: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/

Comment: The console on the phonegap desktop app doesn't log javascript, it's the server log.